# Remove MUI Select Component's border after you click on it - React JS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to remove the border on Select from MUI after I click on it and I can't find the proper CSS to overwrite
I managed to remove the default one, but not **the blue one** after I click the component, as shown in this sandbox
(https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-bash-zgy4km?file=/demo.tsx)

[Image with the blue border I want to remove - appears after I click on Select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpDy8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove it like this

```
<Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={age}
          label="Age"
          onChange={handleChange}
          sx={{
            borderRadius: 0,
            "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
              border: 0
            },
            "&.MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
              border: "none"
            }
          }}
        >
```

Here is the working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-parm-uugeex?file=/demo.tsx:624-1076)